# makes a script run for every call to a package Laravel4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am developing an application with Laravel 4 framework, I developed an admin package for my application,
Question:
how can I make a piece of code executable for every single call to one of the routes of this specific package? where should I put this piece of code?

Comment: Like a helper function?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [route filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters).

```
Route::filter('admin', function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Or if you want this to be revolved out of the IoC container:

```
Route::filter('admin', 'Vendor\Package\Filters\SomeFilter');
```

Then bind it in your routes file:

```
Route::get("/admin", ["before" => "admin", "uses" => "SomeController@method"]);
```

Though you should consider using an [event handler](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events) instead of this, as it seems like that's *actually* what you want, rather than "run this code when this route is hit".

Normally you should be saying "I want this code to be ran when this happens" when dealing with a package, which would be an event.

Answer (score 1):

Define your filter like;

```
Route::filter('filter', function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

or

```
Route::filter('filter', 'Vendor\Package\Filters\SomeFilter');
```

And attach to the group, and define your route within it like so;

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'filter'), function(){

    //Define your routes here

});
```

Comment: Answers should not depend on other answers, and should be standalone.